# Convert my cURL request to chrome Advanced Rest Client request

Tags: web-services, google-chrome, rest, curl

I have following cURL command and it works fine

```
 curl ­-X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -k -v -u admin:admin https://XXX/tenant/list
```

Note I send username,password,content type and payload with my request.

I want to send the same request in Chrome Advanced Rest Client. How can I fill the form in it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try following steps:

1. Open Chrome advanced rest client and enter your url

   `https://yourdomain.com/tenant/list`
2. Select method as POST
3. In Header section enter:

   `Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=`

   Here "YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=" is encoded Base64 value of admin:admin
4. Enter your payload request in payload section.
5. set Content-Type as "application/json"
6. Send the request.

Comment: Tried this , but i get bad request always